# How to wait for function finish before starting with next function?

Tags: node.js, async-await, discord.js

```
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
exports.function1 = async () => {
  const result = await this.function2();
  if (!result) return console.log("result not found in function1");
};
exports.function2 = () => {
  return this.function3();
};
exports.function3 = () => {
  ytdl.getInfo(/*URL For any Youtube video*/, (error, result) => {
    if (error) return console.log(error);

    return info && console.log("found result in function3");
  });
};
```

**The output i am getting is:**

> result not found in function1
>
> found result in function3

*ytdl.getInfo is function that takes URL for a youtube video and returns a callback with json object with information about that video.*
From this code i need result to returned to function1 before moving forward, so i am guessing using await is best option, but await is not working(i am guessing because it does returns promise). what can be done here to make this function wait?

Comment: You need to be more clear as to what you are trying to accomplish and what your code isn't getting done.  Your title should be a brief explanation and in your body of the question, you need to expand on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are awaiting a function that is not async.

Look at this function declaration.

```
exports.function2 = () => {
```

Now look at how you are using it.

```
const result = await this.function2();
```

Do you see the problem? If you do not, you are using await on a function that is not asynchronous, or, in other words, you are not waiting for the function to finish. In order to resolve this, you need to do something as follows:

```
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");

exports.function1 = async () => {
  const result = await this.function2();
  if (!result) return console.log("result not found in function1");
};

exports.function2 = async () => {
  return this.function3();
};

exports.function3 = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ytdl.getInfo(/*URL For any Youtube video*/, (error, result) => {
        if (error) return reject(error);

        resolve(info && console.log("found result in function3"));
      });
  });

};
```

Furthermore, notice that function 3 returns a promise now. You can use promisify like someone noted above, but if you do not want to, you need to wrap the ytdl call in a promise. Returning inside of a callback does not return from the parent function; it is best to use a promise or pass a callback function into the function.

Comment: To add on to this, I would encourage you to use more descriptive function names, but that obviously does not change the functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It worked, turns out i was really bad with promises. After few hit and trials my code is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Callback functions that utilize the common pattern `(error, value) => {}` on it's final argument can be promisified.

```
const util = require('util');
```

then

```js
const pgetInfo = util.promisify(ytdl.getInfo);
let result = await pgetInfo(/*URL For any Youtube video*/);
```

or

```js
const pgetInfo = util.promisify(ytdl.getInfo);
pgetInfo(/*URL For any Youtube video*/)
    .then((result) => { /* result stuff */ })
    .catch((err) => { /* err stuff */ });
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but i didn't use it yet. But i will check it out in future. This method looks pretty easy though.